# How can I create a "partial" that has its own action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application, I render a partial on multiple pages, and in that partial is a variable.  So currently, lets say I have 5 pages that render :partial => "partialname", and inside of partialname is @variable.

Can I have it so that partialname has its own action with @variable instantiated inside, rather than having @variable be called 5 times from each action that renders the partial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would create a `before_filter` on all the methods that need the common behavior.

But if you really want the partial to have its own "action," make a helper method that does whatever "action-y" things you want and then renders the partial. That works out to essentially the same thing. I've done this before to make a template-type partial that contains various pieces of data that need processing.

Answer (score 1):

[Rails Sub-controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704687/rails-sub-controllers/1109088#1109088)

See my answer on this.

Very similar method here, using before filters either using controller inheritance or modules when needed.

Answer (score 0):

you could load @variable from the view:

```
 <% @variable = Variable.find(:whatever) %>
```

but some consider this bad practice in not adhering to strict MVC.  This does have the benefit of supporting fragment caching out of the box:

```
<% cache({:variable_id => :whatever})  do %>
 <% @variable = Variable.find(:whatever) %>
 . . . 
<% end %>
```

Is there a common model that's being rendered in the main views that you could delegate the variable access to?

```
<%=h @model.variable %>
```

Comment: you should escape model.variable, just change that to <%=h model.variable %>

Answer (score 0):

So, is this a problem of code running 5 times per request that you'd rather not? Like, you've got a partial and in it is:

```
@my_var = MyModel.some_expensive_method
```

If so, you could just cache the result in the model:

```
def cached_some_expensive_method
  @some_expensive_method ||= some_expensive_method()
end
```